# Lock trava a referência ou o objeto?

Tags: c#, ponteiro, referência

Quando estou construindo funções thread-safe, eu uso o `lock` para obter prioridade no thread atual e impedir que outros threads acessem o objeto que estou manipulando, mas tenho uma dúvida.

```
List<string> strArray = new ();

List<string> a = strArray;
List<string> b = a;

b.Add("Hello");
```

Agora eu preciso remover um item de forma segura:

```
lock (strArray) {
    strArray.RemoveAt(0);
}
lock (a) {
    strArray.RemoveAt(0);
}
lock (b) {
    strArray.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Minha dúvida é: se eu travar uma referência (`b`), que aponta para outra referência (`a`), o que será bloqueado? A referência (`b`) ou o objeto final (`strArray`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que é a referência? É um objeto por valor que referencia outro objeto (por isso ela chama por referência).

Qual é o objetivo do *lock*? Travar para que outras *threads* não consigam manipular um objeto concorrentemente, certo?

Objetos por valor precisam ser travados? Não!

Então o ponteiro, que é um objeto por valor, não precisa ser travado. Se o fizesse seria um enorme desperdício.

Portanto só sobra o objeto referenciado. É ele que está sendo travado para alteração. Se uma *thread* trava o objeto referenciado, no exemplo a lista, e em outra *thread* tentar travar não vai conseguir.

Não sei o objetivo aí, se foi só para mostrar como seriam os códigos isoladamente, mas não faz sentido travar três vezes na mesma *thread*, como não há concorrência ele trava e destrava em cada um deles em sequência. Ou faz um só para proteger de outra *thread*, ou nem isso se não tem outra *thread*.

De qualquer forma está protegido contra manipulação de outra *thread* nas três remoções. Desde que as outras também usem o `lock`. Sim, o *lock* não consegue interferir em toda execução. Ele é um comando que você pede para travar, e ele te dá isso se não tiver nada travado naquele objeto. Ou seja, se você tentar acessar sem ele o acesso fica livre, porque você não pediu para acessar, só foi lá e acessou. O .NET não é um regulador universal. O `lock` é uma forma do código comunicar que precisa de acesso garantido concorrente, todo mundo tem que concordar com isso. Você tem que por um guarda de trânsito (o `lock`) em todo lugar que vai acessar um objeto com segurança, se não fizer isso o acesso está dado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).